# Combining two arrays in python term by term

Tags: python, arrays, merge, combiners

```
long =np.array(data.Longitude)
lat = np.array(data.Latitude)
coordinates = np.array(385)
for i in range(385):
    coordinates[i] = np.array([lat[i], long[i]])



#x, y = kmeans2(whiten(coordinates), 3, iter = 20)  
#plt.scatter(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1], c=y);
#plt.show()
```

I have a dataset with two columns and I wish to merge the latitude and longitude term by term to apply k means clustering after that.Please help with the array part

Comment: how would you want to merge lat and long?? like a tuple or a string??

Comment: integers preferrably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coordinates = np.array([lat, long])
```

or am I missing sth here...

Comment: what this does is that it combines (all the lat values as one entry) + ',' + (all the longitude entry)..
so effectively i get only one entry in coordinates

Comment: Hmm - I still don't quite get it, it's a numpy 2D-array, you can index it however you like. And if you're not happy with it you can still transpose it by `.T`